# Post the data to server using retrofit in android

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I have tried to post this data to a server using retrofit. 
So I tried to create the Serialized Request to post this data. 
Usually if this request like

```
{
"FirstName":"test",
"LastName":"test",
"EmailAddress":"test@test.com",
"Password":"test",
"DeviceToken":"",
"PushToken":"",
"DeviceType":"test",
"SMSSubscribe":"1",
"EmailSubscribe":"1",
"TermsCondition":"1",
}
```

then I created the Serialized class like this

```
public class RegisterRequest {

@SerializedName("DeviceToken")
public String deviceToken;

@SerializedName("PushToken")
public String pushToken;

@SerializedName("AppVersion")
public String appVersion;

@SerializedName("DevicePlatform")
public String devicePlatform;

@SerializedName("DeviceType")
public String deviceType;

@SerializedName("FirstName")
public String firstName;

@SerializedName("LastName")
public String lastName;

@SerializedName("EmailAddress")
public String email;

@SerializedName("Password")
public String password;

@SerializedName("MobileCountryCode")
public String mobileCountryCode;

@SerializedName("MobileNumber")
public String mobileNumber;

@SerializedName("SMSSubscribe")
public String smsSubscribe;

@SerializedName("EmailSubscribe")
public String emailSubscribe;

@SerializedName("TermsCondition")
public String termsCondition;

@SerializedName("DeviceInformation")
public String deviceInformation;
```

}
then

```
@Headers({TOKEN, CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, LANGUAGE_CODE, APP_VERSION})
@POST("api/RegisterStep1")
Call<CommonResponse> register(@Body RegisterRequest registerRequest);
```

Then I post the data like this

```
 final RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest();
    registerRequest.firstName = givenName;
    registerRequest.lastName = familyName;
    registerRequest.email = email;
    registerRequest.password = password;
    registerRequest.deviceToken = Repository.getDeviceId();
    registerRequest.pushToken = "";
    registerRequest.deviceType = Repository.DEVICE_TYPE;
    registerRequest.appVersion = Repository.APP_VERSION;
    registerRequest.devicePlatform = Repository.DEVICE_PLATFORM;
    registerRequest.mobileNumber = mobileNo;
    registerRequest.mobileCountryCode = mSelectedCountryCode;
    registerRequest.deviceInformation = Repository.DEVICE_INFO;

 Repository.apiService().register(registerRequest).enqueue(new BaseCallback<CommonResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CommonResponse body) {
            super.onSuccess(body);
```

but now I want to know how to create the Serialized class to post this below format data to the server

```
{
"REG_Company": {
     "ReferenceCode":"ReferenceCode",
     "CompanyType":"1",
    "CompanyName": "Test",
    "CompanyEmailAddress": "test@test.com",
    "CompanyTier": "1",
    "ContactNumber": "99999",
    "OilChangePerMonth": "1",
    "OilChangePercentage": "1",
    "ShellHelixQty": "1",
    "Remarks": "1"
},
 "REG_CompanyAddress": {
        "AddressType":"1",
        "Address1":"Address1",
        "Address2":"Address2",
         "StreetName":"StreetName",
         "CompanyCity":"CompanyCity",
         "CompanyState":"CompanyState",
         "PostalCode":"PostalCode",
         "Longitude":"Longitude",
          "Latitude":"Latitude"
 },
 "REG_CompanyService": [
        {"ServiceID":1
        },{"ServiceID":2}]
        ,
 "REG_CompanyHours": [
        {"WeekDay":1,
        "IsOpen":1,
        "StartTime":1,
        "CloseTime":1
        }, {"WeekDay":1,
        "IsOpen":1,
        "StartTime":1,
        "CloseTime":1
        }],
 "REG_Member": {
     "UserID":"UserID",
     "UserPassword":"UserPassword",
    "Salutation": "1",
    "FirstName": "FirstName",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "MobileNumber": "MobileNumber",
    "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress",
    "Gender": "1",
    "ContactPreference": "1",
    "RegistrationType": "1",
    "RegistrationMode": "1"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code as serialized model class.

```
@SerializedName("REG_CompanyAddress")
public CompanyAddress address = new CompanyAddress();

@SerializedName("REG_CompanyService")
public List<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();  

public static class Service {

    @SerializedName("ServiceID")
    public Integer serviceID;

}   

 public static class CompanyAddress {

    @SerializedName("AddressType")
    public String addressType;

    @SerializedName("Address1")
    public String address1;

    .......
    Your code 

    }
```

Like this you ca create for the other fields

Answer (score 1):

Manually defining POJOs for JSON serialization is a tedious task and can be (at least partially) automated by using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). For your JSON it generates this output:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("REG_Company")
@Expose
public REGCompany rEGCompany;
@SerializedName("REG_CompanyAddress")
@Expose
public REGCompanyAddress rEGCompanyAddress;
@SerializedName("REG_CompanyService")
@Expose
public List<REGCompanyService> rEGCompanyService = null;
@SerializedName("REG_CompanyHours")
@Expose
public List<REGCompanyHour> rEGCompanyHours = null;
@SerializedName("REG_Member")
@Expose
public REGMember rEGMember;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.REGCompany.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class REGCompany {

@SerializedName("ReferenceCode")
@Expose
public String referenceCode;
@SerializedName("CompanyType")
@Expose
public String companyType;
@SerializedName("CompanyName")
@Expose
public String companyName;
@SerializedName("CompanyEmailAddress")
@Expose
public String companyEmailAddress;
@SerializedName("CompanyTier")
@Expose
public String companyTier;
@SerializedName("ContactNumber")
@Expose
public String contactNumber;
@SerializedName("OilChangePerMonth")
@Expose
public String oilChangePerMonth;
@SerializedName("OilChangePercentage")
@Expose
public String oilChangePercentage;
@SerializedName("ShellHelixQty")
@Expose
public String shellHelixQty;
@SerializedName("Remarks")
@Expose
public String remarks;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.REGCompanyAddress.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class REGCompanyAddress {

@SerializedName("AddressType")
@Expose
public String addressType;
@SerializedName("Address1")
@Expose
public String address1;
@SerializedName("Address2")
@Expose
public String address2;
@SerializedName("StreetName")
@Expose
public String streetName;
@SerializedName("CompanyCity")
@Expose
public String companyCity;
@SerializedName("CompanyState")
@Expose
public String companyState;
@SerializedName("PostalCode")
@Expose
public String postalCode;
@SerializedName("Longitude")
@Expose
public String longitude;
@SerializedName("Latitude")
@Expose
public String latitude;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.REGCompanyHour.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class REGCompanyHour {

@SerializedName("WeekDay")
@Expose
public Integer weekDay;
@SerializedName("IsOpen")
@Expose
public Integer isOpen;
@SerializedName("StartTime")
@Expose
public Integer startTime;
@SerializedName("CloseTime")
@Expose
public Integer closeTime;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.REGCompanyService.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class REGCompanyService {

@SerializedName("ServiceID")
@Expose
public Integer serviceID;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.REGMember.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class REGMember {

@SerializedName("UserID")
@Expose
public String userID;
@SerializedName("UserPassword")
@Expose
public String userPassword;
@SerializedName("Salutation")
@Expose
public String salutation;
@SerializedName("FirstName")
@Expose
public String firstName;
@SerializedName("LastName")
@Expose
public String lastName;
@SerializedName("MobileNumber")
@Expose
public String mobileNumber;
@SerializedName("EmailAddress")
@Expose
public String emailAddress;
@SerializedName("Gender")
@Expose
public String gender;
@SerializedName("ContactPreference")
@Expose
public String contactPreference;
@SerializedName("RegistrationType")
@Expose
public String registrationType;
@SerializedName("RegistrationMode")
@Expose
public String registrationMode;

}
```

Of course, you can further refactor the generated code, e.g. by making the classes referenced by the main one inner static.

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner classes and ArrayLists. For example, if you have:

```
{
    "A": 1,
    "B": {
        "C": "d"
    }
    "D": [
        1,
        2]
}
```

You will have:

```
public  class Model {
    private int A;
    private B B;
    private ArrayList<Integer> D;
    // Getters and setters

    public class B {
        private String C;
        // Getters and setters
}
```